# How to prevent finger friction when using touchscreen for a long time?

Tags: touchscreen, input-device

When I start dragging around touchscreen my finger moves smoothly and easily. However the more I use touchscreen the more resistive the screen/finger gets which makes moving around less pleasant.

How to prevent it?

Comment: Can you use a stylus?

Comment: @gunbaster363, No, it's capacitive screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely the most commons solution to this is to use a screen protector.  Take a look on [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=screen+protectors&x=0&y=0), or just go to your local phone store or mall and pick one up.  I tend to prefer the ones that are more of a matte type of material.

The problem is actually caused by the oils on your fingers causing friction with the screen.  Usually wiping your phone's screen off with a damp cloth, or some screen cleaning solution will do the trick. Make sure when you are cleaning it to not get any of the liquid inside any of the holes on your phone.  If you do, remove the battery, and place the phone in a cup of rice for 24 hours.  Also, after wiping your phone down, wash your hands and dry them thoroughly.  This should remove all of the friction-causing oil from your hands/phone.

Comment: Don't put your phone in a bag of rice. Search for "rice" on this page for several reasons why. https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/what-to-do-if-you-spilled-water-on-your-laptop/

Answer (score 2):

I would use a nice lint-free cloth to wipe down the screen whenever it starts getting gummed up.

Other than that, you might try using lighter pressure.  Modern touch-screens are very sensitive and using lighter pressure will keep oils off your screen while also reducing friction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are gaming try using a small amount or flour or baby powder rubbed onto your thumbs. Gives it a glass like feel.

Answer (score 1):

Wash your hands, then spay a tiny amount of anti-persperant onto your thumbs. Works a treat for me.

Answer (score 0):

From me it becomes a issue when gaming I just tape a piece of Scotch tape for the tip of my thumbs and it works perfectly